# Find date in a range and show the result

Tags: excel

I have small query. I have a database in excel in which prices are changed in each month. I want a formula that will find a value in a range and then show the result.

For example:
Let say I have a cell in which date is entered say Cell A7.
I want a result in Cell J7.
The formula should find the date in a range. e.g. 
if Cell A7 has a date "Feb 12, 2015", then the formula should find this date in a range and multiply the Cell H7 and I7. If this date is not found in range, then the result should be shown 0.

What I have made a logic is something like this.
If A7>=Jan 01, 2015 and <=Feb 28, 2015, then H7*I7 else 0.
But unable to work it out.

Please help me out in this matter.

Thanks.
Salman Khan

Answer (score 0):

I created a date range to compare against. 2 cells located in D2 and F2 which would theoretically be used to alter which date range you would like to compare against. D2 value is (4/1/2015), F2 value is (4/30/2015)

In A7 I have today's date (4/9/2015) in A8 I have (4/15/2015) in A9 I have (5/1/2015)

Column H is my cost column so H7 = 5, H8 = 3, H9 = 6

Column I is my quantity column (multiplier) so H7 = 2, H8 = 5, H9 = 4

Finally Column J is my formula results. Here is my formula:

```
IF(AND(A7>$D$2,A7<$F$2),H7*I7,0)
```

I drag that formula down my J Column and my J values are: 
J7 = 10, J8 = 15, J9 = 0

If I change the date in A9 to (4/16/2015), the value in J9 becomes 24.